# Adding numbers to string name using a loop

Tags: javascript, android

So I want to make this code work with a loop. something like:

```
for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 90);
        String cycle[i] = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView cyc[i] = findViewById(R.id.cyc[i]);
        cyc1.setText(cycle[i]);
}
```

But this won't work i guess?

That's the code I want to replace so it's much more concise.

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 90);
        String cycle1 = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView cyc1 = findViewById(R.id.cyc1);
        cyc1.setText(cycle1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 90);
        String cycle2 = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView cyc2 = findViewById(R.id.cyc2);
        cyc2.setText(cycle2);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 90);
        String cycle3 = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView cyc3 = findViewById(R.id.cyc3);
        cyc3.setText(cycle3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `R.id.cyc[i]`.

Instead try creating an array of ID's like `[R.id.cyc1, R.id.cyc2, R.id.cyc3]` and then iterate on them.